# Corona - SpriteHelper files not working on iPhone 4 and 4S

Tags: sprite, iphone-4, retina-display, coronasdk

I've been playing with Corona for a couple of days and everything was going well until I tried to put the game on my iPhone 4. The normal @2x images work fine by using the **display.newImageRect** method and by putting the following in my **config.lua** file:

```
imageSuffix = {
    ["@2x"] = 2,
        ["-hd"] = 2 
}
```

However, SpriteHelper outputs 4 files, 2 **HD** files and 2 **SD** files. Like so:

- player-hd.png
- player-hd.lua
- player.png
- player.lua

I'm creating the sprite etc like this:

```
local sprite = require( "sprite" )
local playerData = require( "animations/player" )
local playerSpriteData = playerData.getSpriteSheetData()
local playerSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheetFromData( "animations/player.png", playerSpriteData )
local playerSpriteSet = sprite.newSpriteSet(playerSpriteSheet, 1, 7)
player = sprite.newSprite(playerSpriteSet)
```

These files work fine in the iPhone 4 corona simulator, however once I build it and put it on my device none of SpriteHelper files are displayed. I've tried changing the ***-hd*** bit of the files to ***@2x*** put this did nothing. I've even tried putting @2x in the above code to try and make it retina only supported, but again nothing changed.

Has anyone else had this issue? Any advice would be great as I really want to play test the game on my device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your corona version, folders may not be supported on device. so try to put your player.png file directly on your project root folder. Also please, write on the dedicated sprite helper forum in order to help you faster.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to make a different. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable retina mode from the app delegate.

Remove this line:

```
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```